# URL with tilde in it not correctly working in body of answer

Tags: bug

[This question](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/90025/80) has an inlined link that fails to go to the right page.  The same (to my eyes) link in the comments goes to the right PDF.

When I paste both URLs into a text editor, the problem becomes apparent:

[image: Two URLs in plain text]

The erroneous URL is substituting `%7E` for the tilde character, and this doesn't go to the right page.